# WordPress Multisite 404 error on posts and subsites

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, multisite

I have installed WordPress multisite and my main site is working but the posts and subsite going to 404 I searched a lot and no luck. my Wordpress is configured in the subdirectory at http://arabyouthsurvey.com/newsite/media-center/

I have two sites in it.

Site 1: it is working but it's posts going to 404. I can access the wp-admin for this site too.

Site 2: it is completely going to 404. also cannot access wp-admin

Here is my htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /newsite/media-center/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I added these lines on my wp-config.php

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'arabyouthsurvey.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/newsite/media-center/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

I have no extra plugin installed and I tried by deactivating all plugins but the issue still exists.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=multisite+404

Comment: thankyou i fixed this issue by changing php configuration from server :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed this issue by changing php configuration of my server

it was serving php by nginx i changed it to apache and my issue gone.

Answer (score 6):

So I struggled and struggled with this error
I'd moved an existing working server to a new Ubuntu 16.xxx server and it all went t***ts up.

Wordpress - MultiSite - SubDomain install
Main site working correctly like  - www.domain.com

Subdomain sites like **testing.domain.com** OR **www.anotherdomain.com**

- would work correctly but only on their default home page
- would work
  correctly on pages and posts if using post ID rather than pretty
  permalinks.

**.htaccess** file was all according to the recommended settings
wp-config.php all set up similarly

Sites vhost config files for subdomains configured correctly

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/web04
        ServerName subsite.domain.uk
        ServerAlias www.subsite.domain.uk subsite.web04.domain.uk

  ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.uk

    <Directory "/websites/www/html/web04">
            order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            AllowOverride All
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks
    </Directory>

    LogLevel debug rewrite:trace8

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/subsite-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/subsite-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

THE ISSUE WAS

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf

MAKE SURE THAT THE FOLLOWING LINES ARE CORRECT AND CHANGE THE DEFAULT OF

**AllowOverride None to All**

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted 
</Directory>
```

Comment: Robert, I have been struggling with this same problem for a while now. I have my installed wp in my subdomain. Why is your <Directory "/websites/www/html/web04"> path different from DocumentRoot /var/www/html/web04?

Posted a SO question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62113159/wordpress-permalink-issue-w-subdomains

Could you please help?!?

Comment: Never mind, I had initiall set allowoverride to all in <Directory> v/s <Directory /var/www/>.

It's working now!!

Comment: Thank you, Robert! This fixed our issue on a brand new Wordpress Multisite!

Comment: I want to say after spending several hours looking for answers to this problem this answer solved my problem immediately! I was seeking to find out why WordPress Multisite using subdirectories kept returning a 404 but would load the main site. I've done a little research on this and it appears that "AllowOverride None" means that any .htaccess file in the file system will be ignored but when set to "AllowOverride All" will follow directives set by the .htaccess file. So basically WordPress is not able to communicate properly with the web server and therefore cannot load any sites.

Answer (score 0):

I also found this problem after a server upgrade.

The following resorted access to all WordPress subsites:

`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

MAKE SURE THAT THE FOLLOWING LINES ARE CORRECT AND CHANGE THE DEFAULT OF

```
AllowOverride None to All

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted 
</Directory>
```