# Wordpress Permalink Issue w/ Subdomains

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, subdomain, permalinks

**My setup:** I have domain.com pointing to Server 1 and have set up blog.domain.com to point to another wordpress Server 2 that hosts multiple wordpress sites. Server 2 has multiple wordpress sites in a single Ubuntu server as per [these](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multiple-wordpress-sites-on-a-single-ubuntu-vps) instructions. Because this manual is outdated, I also follow wordpress virtual host configuration based on Step 4 detailed in [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04) post. Describing my setup up front because I'm not sure if my problem is because of this setup.

**Question:**

Based on this setup, Wordpress works fine with the default permalink option. Below are the details in my conf file

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain
ServerName blog.domain.com
ServerAlias blog.domain.com
<Directory "/var/www/domain">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

When plain permalinks are selected, my htaccess file in /var/www/domain is empty and everything works fine.However, when I change the permalink to Post name (blog.domain.com/sample-post/) the homepage (blog.domain.com) works fine but my individual post url (blog.domain.com/sample-post/) does not work. My htaccess file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

WordPress Address (URL) = blog.domain.com
Site Address (URL) = blog.domain.com

Could you please help resolve this. I'd like permalinks to be enabled but have been stuck with this issue for several months. Really appreciate all your comments & feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by following instructions by Robert in this thread - [WordPress Multisite 404 error on posts and subsites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43795522/wordpress-multisite-404-error-on-posts-and-subsites)